# How to connect application to SQL Server 2008 through remote access

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, remote-server

Is there any way to connect to the database which is at remote server using ASP.NET ? I checked for TCP/IP ports at remote desktop. They are also enabled I have tried specifying IP address and SQL Server name in the connection string but it shows the following error:

> (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Setup a VPN connection between the two.

Comment: how to set  VPN connection

Answer (score 0):

Must be change some configuration on `Sql Server Configuration Manager`

- Open `Sql Server Configuration Manager` And Select on tab `SQL Server Network Connection`
- Double click Protocols For ... Change to Enable **YES**
- Click IP Addresses tab and set **IPAll TCP Port** **1433**

> `1433` is a default `SQL Server` Port. If you want to set another port ,
>   port must be unavailable and define port on `Windows Firewall With Advanced Security`

you can also review the document about the topic [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-a-server-to-listen-on-a-specific-tcp-port)